# Electron Builder user-editable resources?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm making kind of a digital signage app using electron, and the user can provide his own backgrounds, fonts, musics, and such. So in my app there is a "backgrounds" folder, a "fonts" folder, ... The user can put their stuff in there, and the app will automatically load those and show them as options.

I included some defaults as well, but the user can remove them if he wants.

Though when I build electron using `electron-builder` these folders are build into an `app.asar` file. I then found I could use the `extraResources` to include these files outside of `app.asar`, however then the app can't find them any more, as it will still look for them in `app.asar`.

So how can I include these folders in the build, and make it so the app will actually find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using `path.join(path.dirname(app.getPath('exe')), fileName);` to find files next to the exe.